# Express.js:how to use different middlewares based on NODE_ENV?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two middlewares, router1 for prod and router2 for test and dev.
How to use different middlewares based on NODE_ENV?

How about the following codes?

```
if( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod' ) {
    app.use('/', router1);
} else {
    app.use('/', router2);
}
```

Any better solutions?
Thanks

Comment: that's exactly how you would do it.  I mean you could knock that down to a one line statement like `app.use('/', process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod' ? router1 : router2);` but that's the best you can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this to have a legible set of available environments (you may need staging and test at one point), and that way you wouldn't have to modify code any time you add a new env to the object.

```
var routers = {
  prod: /* declare prod router */,
  dev: /* declare dev router */,
};

app.use('/', routers[process.env.NODE_ENV] || routers.dev);
```

Comment: Or even more compact: `app.use('/', routers[process.env.NODE_ENV] || routers.dev);`